# Design View on SharePoint Project Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

Hi I am creating an application page for SharePoint 2010

But i ran into a little issue.

First I create a Empty SharePoint Project then I added an Application Page item to the project

When i tried to add controls i am only capable of doing so in the Source View

Some one knows how to enable the design view for this type of project?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Design view may not available for SharePoint Developers in VS.NET because NOT all dependencies (and most importantly master page and other scripts, styles used by master page) are not available to VS.NET's project environment. So VS.NET may not be able to render the page correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The Design view of the designer is disabled for application pages.

You can only design the page in the Source view of the designer.

See
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231581.aspx

Answer (score 1):

here is a trick for this little problem:

add a user control to your project.  copy all the markup code over to this user control.  design away, then copy the markup back into your application page to start refining your code to work as a sharepoint item.